# crtmp unable to read data tcpcarrier.cpp error

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-12.04, gstreamer, rtmpd

I have server with apache2 listening on port 808 instead of port 80 or 8080. I have a flash program which genrated video stream from webcam on client side and send it to server at ip address with rtmp protocol like "rtmp:///flvplayback/"

it publishes the stream to that ip address

1 ) on local machine the string looks like

"rtmp://192.168.1.12/flvplayback/"

and works fine.

2 ) on remote machine i.e VPS the string looks like

"rtmp://222.222.222.222/flvplayback/"

and here the following error is generated

(crtmpserver running on VPS is generating this error ) .... /tcpcarrier.cpp:78 Unable to read data. 111.111.111.111:33984 -> 222.222.222.222:1935 ....

I am not sure why this error is being genetrated.... I am using ubuntu12.04 crtmpserverr build from Download section of site rtmpd.com The same build works totally fine on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should follow the steps here: http://wiki.rtmpd.com/quickbuild
The builds on the site are quite old. The sources are much newer

Can you also provide some log files as well? I don't remember exactly... did you put this question on the crtmpserver's mailing list as well?

Best regards,
Andrei

Comment: Yes I have posted the question on crtmpserver mailing list as well and one more query on google groups' crtmpserver group. Andei I would like to send you mail on this issue at your address contact@rtmpd.com